# NoMethodError: undefined method `users.created_at' for #<User:0x007fb548e8c128>

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using [by_star](https://github.com/radar/by_star) gem and nearly all methods appear to be working. The only two methods I am struggling with are '**next**' and '**previous**'.

I get the following error when trying to invoke these from the console.

```
1.9.3p125 :014 > User.last.next
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY "users"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
NoMethodError: undefined method `users.created_at' for #<User:0x007fb548e8c128>
```

Gem version

```
by_star (2.1.0.beta2) from git://github.com/radar/by_star (at master)
```

Rails version 3.2.11.

Any tips on why this might be happening?

Thanks

*Edit: content of the post updated with guidance from the commenters below.*

Comment: "To find the record after this one call `next` on any model instance:". The word *instance* is probably important, having a look at the `next` example is probably a good idea too.

Comment: true, calling next on Class will not get you anywhere, from documentation Post.last.next means he finds the last post and them on it calls the next method. By the way thanks for the gem, good one.

Comment: Ah - I see your point. That helps me somewhat, yet I seem to encounter another issue `1.9.3p125 :014 > User.last.next
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY "users"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
NoMethodError: undefined method `users.created_at' for #<User:0x007fb548e8c128>` The User model does have the created_at attribute `1.9.3p125 :015 > User
 => User(id: integer, first_name: string, last_name: string, email: string, telephone_number: string, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, username: string)`

Comment: just added this gem to my project and got the same error in console

Comment: Yes, I am using a console. I just fired up the full ROR app but it produces the same error message. The schema is pointing to the "users" plural which follows the standard generator pattern. What am I missing?

Comment: this could be a gem bug unless we are doing it wrong, tried with User.last.previous("created_at") and still returns error.